# United airlines: ordering my ticket online keeps coming up with please use a valid date of birth

Tags: tickets, online-resources, united-airlines

I'm trying to book a ticket online with United Airlines and it keeps asking to enter a valid date of birth.

I have tried all combinations but it won't take it, i.e m/d/y

Comment: For us to help you figure out what's wrong with your entry, we need to know what you entered.

Comment: Did you try with the "international standard" ISO-8601 form of yyyy-mm-dd? Or failing that the non-US form of dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: When I tried it, it clearly shows it should be entered as `mm/dd/yyyy` and indeed entering `06/19/1953` worked just fine.  Are you using the US site or something else?  What flag appears in the upper right corner of the page?

Comment: Are you booking in the United States? (I'm assuming that if you were using a county-local version of the website, it might have a different date format)

Comment: Change the browser :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something with the following format: mm/dd/yyyy

Such as 10/30/1981 for 30th of October 1981.

If it still does not work, try again with different browsers, in this order:

1. Firefox
2. Google chrome
3. Internet explorer (minimum version 10)

Comment: If it still does not work, switch off computer, get a cup of coffee, switch back on, try again. If it fails, reboot again, clear cookies and try anew. (General internet trouble shooting solutions.)